# C++ shared_ptr how to delete a pointee with multiple shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Im working on this project,

The problem Im having is that the an object, does not really get deleted when I need it to be because it has a couple of shared pointers pointing to it.

How do I solve this,please help.

Comment: Well this sounds like that you have a design problem. If you need to delete it while it is in multiple shared_ptr that will not work. 
You would break the code. 

You should be more specific what you exactly want to achieve

Comment: That makes no sense. If it's shared, a single owner can't just decide to take it away. That's not sharing.

Comment: @GMan:  It's elementary-school style "I'm taking my object and going home" sharing.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is by design.  As long as an object is owned by one or more `shared_ptr` smart pointers, it will not be destroyed.  Ownership of the object is *shared* by all of the smart pointers that have ownership and the object can't be destroyed until all of the owners are done with it.  This is what shared ownership is.

If you want to be able to destroy the object while there are still some references to it, you can use `weak_ptr` for those references.

Comment: +1 sounds like those hanging refs should be via weak_ptr alright

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the use_count of a `shared_ptr` by using its `reset()` method.

If you do this for every pointer which holds the instance, the last `reset()` will destroy the object it points to.

```
shared_ptr<Class> myPointer1( new Class() ); //myPointer holds an instance of Class
shared_ptr<Class> myPointer2 = myPointer1; //use_count == 2
myPointer1.reset(); //use_count == 1
myPointer2.reset(); //instance of class will be destroyed
```

But you probably have a problem with you design, shared_ptr should automatically go out of focus when certain objects are destroyed or methods end. Perhaps you should have a look at the points where the shared_ptrs still hold pointers to the object and check if they shouldn't hold the object anymore.

Comment: That won't delete the object if it is shared by other `shared_ptr` instances.

Comment: You're right, just researched this and saw, that I was wrong. I'll edit this out.